# Flutter lint rules - Avoid method calls or property accesses on a "dynamic" target

Tags: flutter, lint

I am resolving lint issues, so I want help to solve this one of Avoid method calls or property accesses on a "dynamic" target.

My code is below:

```
class FlavorValues {
  String? baseUrl;
  String? name;
  String? ocpApimSubscriptionKey;
  

  FlavorValues(dynamic value) {
    baseUrl = value['baseUrl']; // value throwing the lint
    name = value['appName']; // value throwing the lint
    ocpApimSubscriptionKey = value['ocpApimSubscriptionKey'];
    
  }
}
```

the line throwing the lint is:
baseUrl = value['baseUrl'];

- value is the one throwing the lint rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Map` instead.

Like so:

```
  FlavorValues(Map<String, dynamic> value) {
     baseUrl = value['baseUrl'];
    name = value['appName'];
    ocpApimSubscriptionKey = value['ocpApimSubscriptionKey'];
  }
```